# iPython vs. Matlab - Differences in Simple Multiplication

Tags: matlab, ipython

I was hoping that I could get some assistance with this.

I'm running a simple script in Matlab:

```
Ao=1.476E21
XN2=0.6
XO2=0.03
P=1 %atm
T=2000%K

Ru=82.057 %atm*cm^3/mol-K

dXNO_dt=Ao*XN2*(XO2^(1/2))*exp(-67520/T)*((P/(Ru*T))^(1/2))
```

which yields the correct (data confirmed) answer of:

```
dXNO_dt =

  824.9806
```

However, when I switch over to iPython and use a similar script:

```
from numpy import *

Ao=1.476E21
XN2=0.6
XO2=0.03
P=1 #atm
T=2000#K

Ru=82.057 #atm*cm^3/mol-K

dXNO_dt=Ao*XN2*(XO2**(1/2))*exp(-67520/T)*((P/(Ru*T))**(1/2))
print 'dXNO_dt = {0}'.format(dXNO_dt)
```

I get the baffling answer of:

```
>>> dXNO_dt = 1517837.30697
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening? I'm a huge noob when it comes to figuring out the deeper issues like this.

This is in Python 2.7.8, IPython 2.3.1

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get that in Python. I have used 2 versions to do sanity check. For Python 3.4.x, I get 824.9805522208239. I also didn't get that for Python 3.3.x. Exactly same result. What are you using?

Comment: This is in Python 2.7.8, IPython 2.3.1

Comment: sorry - forgot to put it on iPython as I don't have it, but the results are from Python normal IDLE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is integer division.  In python 2, dividing an integer by an integer will give an integer result, so `1/2 == 0`.  If you use `0.5` or `1.0/2.0` as your exponents then you'll get the right answer.  Similarly you need to use `-67520.0/T`.

The following gives me a result of 824.98055222082394

```
dXNO_dt=Ao*XN2*(XO2**(1.0/2.0))*exp(-67520.0/T)*((P/(Ru*T))**(1.0/2.0))
```

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. If you want a more intuitive behavior of `/`, you can use `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: Even experienced programmers get bitten by this issue every now and then. It is worth mentioning that the behavior was changed for Python 3 (or already under Python 2 with `from __future__ ...`), see [PEP 238](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) for details. This is one of the reasons why beginners should use Python 3, if possible.

Comment: Numeric values in Matlab are doubles by default.